# How to prevent computer teammate from making peace with your enemy

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I have a computer teammate and whenever I am at war, my teammate keeps making peace with the other team.

Can I do something to prevent this? It (of course) always happens just when I'm about to breach city defenses.

Comment: Hm, Civ 4 had a 'permanent alliances' option, but that seems to be missing in Civ 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Like real life, your allies can back out of your plans at the least convenient times.

I do have one suggestion, but its not ideal. To see how likely your ally is to make peace, try seeing how much they would charge you to make peace in the diplomacy menu. If its a lot, they are probably going to continue the war, and if its only a little or nothing, you probably shouldn't rely on their help.

Comment: Yea, it is not so much that they don't help. My big issue is, that they like to make peace, which will make peace for me aswell, since we're on the same team. Then, just before breaching a city, all my troops are outside their borders, and my enemy is guarded by a peace treaty.

Comment: Ohhhh. In a team game. Not used to thinking of that. All I can say is that unfortunately Civ 5 seems to have been designed around single-player free-for-all, at the cost of everything else.